# How can I concisely compare a single variable to many different values?

Tags: c++, comparison, shortcut

I know you can write a statement like:

```
if (num1 != a && num1 != b && num1 != c ..........&& num1 != z)
   (do something);
```

But is there an easier way to compare the num1 variable to 26 other variables? Kinda like:

```
if (num1 != a,b,c,d,e,f,g.......)
   (do something);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `a..g` are contiguous constant/enum values then just use a range check.

```
if (num >= a && num <= g)
{
    do_something();
}
else
{
    do_something_else();
}
```

If they are non-contiguous but constant then maybe use a switch statement.

```
switch (num)
{
    case a:
    case b:
    case c:
    case d:
    case e:
    case f:
    case g:
        do_something();
        break;

    default:
        do_something_else();
        break;
}
```

otherwise if they are just arbitrary variables or expressions then you may have just have to do it with multiple tests.

Comment: I like this method, now is the default statement run when num doesnt match any of the cases?

Comment: @Dave Fraser: yes, `default` ia a "catch all" which handles all values of `num` for which there is no explicit case.

Comment: @Paul R Thanks alot that really helps me out.

Comment: @Dave: If an answer solves you problem, accept is as correct using the tick on the left.

Comment: switches do not work with variables. The case statments have to be compile time constants.

Comment: @Martin: He did say, "If they're constant"

Comment: Can't we use OR operator? In TCL following was done %
% if {$a == (1 ||  2)} {
puts "yup"
} else {
puts "asf"
}
yup

}
yup

Comment: @vaichidrewar: no, at least not in C, C++ and related languages (the original question is about C++).

Answer (score 5):

You can put `a, ... ,z` into a [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/set/) and then use the `find` method of that set to check if `num1` is in there. This has logarithmic complexity, but does not allow for short-circuiting.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have a good hashing algorithm for your data type (or you're working only with primitive types), `std::unordered_set` provides this with constant complexity.

Comment: @ildjarn: `std::unordered_set` exists only in C++0x. Before that, you would have to use `boost::unordered_set`.

Comment: Only left out the usual `std::`/`std::tr1::`/`boost::` disclaimer for brevity. :-]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a good code design should not include so many sequence of conditions.

If  your case is exactly the way it is, that is trying to see if a number exists in a list, where the list is actually a collection of variables. You could simply enter those numbers into the list( vector ) and perform find operation.

Answer (score 0):

Store the variables in a seperate class / struck if the situation allows for that.

If your question is more about if there is a syntax in c++ to allow a smaler if statement, then perhaps make that clearer in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::find:

```
static ValueType values[] = { a, b, ... };
//  ...
if ( std::find( begin( values ), end( values ), num )
        == end( values ) )
```